# Network Error using Facebook's Swift SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, swift4

I'm using Swift 4.0 and Xcode 11.1 and I'm getting a "Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server" once I click on the Facebook login button I created with the help of the documentation. I imported the Swift SDK from Facebook by putting the following in my PodFile:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

After I did `pod install` and `pod update`, I was able to compile with only Framework warnings such as semantic issues which I don't feel relate to the issue here. One warning I am getting is telling me this: `Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Project_Name_Here/Info.plist'.` although I'm not sure it relates to the problem either.

Here is my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore

...
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
...
```

and here is my `ViewController.swift` file:

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [.email])
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Here are the messages I get in the console before clicking the button (and after the app runs without any errors):

```
2017-11-12 01:45:32.501025-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.501301-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.501791-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.502636-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.504182-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.504688-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:32.740935-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/np/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DBE38B81-E28F-485E-B967-A76E1D2B019C/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-11-12 01:45:32.743511-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-11-12 01:45:32.751346-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
2017-11-12 01:45:33.146213-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598380] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-11-12 01:45:33.146353-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598380] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
```

I got the simulator bug errors after updating to Xcode 9.1 as I thought that may fix things but it just made it worse. The errors I get after clicking the Login to Facebook button are:

```
2017-11-12 01:45:43.550223-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2017-11-12 01:45:43.551413-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
2017-11-12 01:45:43.553518-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2017-11-12 01:45:45.850963-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598259] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
2017-11-12 01:45:45.942460-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598369] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2017-11-12 01:45:45.944297-0600 Project_Name_Here[50388:41598369] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
```

I've tried googling the individual errors but all have said to put in the info.plist files the proper credentials, but I've already done that and it hasn't fixed anything. The TIC messages are related to TCP/IP connections but I haven't messed with any options as I've just been following basic tutorials on getting the Facebook SDK setup and working.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in you info.plist

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>FB_APP_ID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APPLICATION_NAME</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Yes I have done that already. Even if I didn't, that shouldn't be causing a network error though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly [but disturbing] issue, I had the same problem for a week. Finally found a solution from a different forum:

"I found Avast's "web shield" was causing the issue. To disable it, open Avast, then preferences > web shield > disable. You can just enable it again when you're not using the simulator. I have no idea how it just randomly got turned on because this issue just started happening out of nowhere."

;)